# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

I have a ArrayList in which I insert data from SQL query.

```
ArrayList<Integer> intArray = new ArrayList<>();

 while (result.next())
 {
 intArray.add(result.getInt("CNT"));     // Insert the result into Java Array List
 }
```

Then I use this ArrayList to insert the data into Java Object:

```
dc = new DCDataObj(
             intArray.get(0),
             intArray.get(1),
             intArray.get(2),
             intArray.get(3),
             .........................
```

But sometimes the arrayList is short that the attributes of the Java Object and I get 
`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 39, Size: 39`

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Last question was with 40, wasn't it ?

Comment: Firstly, hard-code referencing the indices in your arraylist makes for very firm code, that isn't easy to manage. By passing in the whole arraylist, for example, and letting the DCDataObj deal with it internally with a loop, you will avoid this problem.

Comment: @dystroy I thought you were being funny but good grief he actually did. O_o

Answer (score 0):

You can't build your Object if it needs X parameters, with only a List of X - 1 elements.

So the question is not How you can do this but WHAT do you want to do.

You could at least test the size of your list, and build the object only if you have enough elements.